# Setting a Form Input Value With IE9 (Getting An Error - Unable to set value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

My PHP code looks as such:

```
<a id='next_page' HREF='#' onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('page_to_show').value='" . ($page + 1) . "'; return false;\" rel='facebox'>[Next $display_per_page]</a>
```

As you can see, I am using `document.getElementById('page_to_show').value` to set the value of the hidden field "page_to_show". I have also tried setting the value of a regular text input field, and I've encountered the same error. I've also tried `.Value` instead of `.value` - no luck. This code works in IE8 and FF 3.6.17. Why not IE9? It is sound code, correct? Thank you!

Oh, I've also tried jQuery's method of `$("#page_to_show").val("Page Num");` and although it hasn't thrown a Javascript error,it doesn't change anything.

I've also tried a temp fix of adding "" however that didn't work either!

Comment: Is your `page_to_show` input in DOM while `next_page` is clcicked?

Comment: I believe so. How would I double check that?

Comment: If you could paste more code i will write you:)

Comment: It's tough to post more code, because the form pops up in a jQuery facebox, and then when the form is submitted, it displays the results in another div. It is in this div where the "Next" link is placed, referring back to the form.

Comment: What does the generated link look like without the php code in it?

Comment: There is no need for the `javascript:` label in the onclick. Remove it.

Comment: @epascarello <a rel="facebox" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('page_to_show').value='1'; return false;" href="#" id="next_page">[Next 10]</a>

Comment: well it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/9Zsr3/  (oops that was IE8 please try in IE9)

Comment: Here's something weird for ya. It wasn't the code. That error was from earlier code, not my updated code. For whatever reason, IE9 isn't refreshing my PHP code! Even if I shift-click refresh, it doesn't refresh my code. I had to exit the browser and open it again for it to refresh. Perhaps thats a setting. Thank you guys! That explains why it was so weird that it wasn't working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something weird for ya. It wasn't the code. That error was from earlier code, not my updated code. For whatever reason, IE9 isn't refreshing my PHP code! Even if I shift-click refresh, it doesn't refresh my code. I had to exit the browser and open it again for it to refresh. Perhaps thats a setting. Thank you guys! That explains why it was so weird that it wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that your input has an `id` and not just a `name` attribute?
Additionally, I've seen IE get sticky when trying to set the value of input fields that exist outside of a `<form>`.

Comment: It has an ID and a Name Attribute, and it is inside of the <form> tags. Thank you though!

Comment: Also, not READONLY, DISABLED, display:hidden, or accidentally sharing an ID with another input or element?

Comment: Here's something weird for ya. It wasn't the code. That error was from earlier code, not my updated code. For whatever reason, IE9 isn't refreshing my PHP code! Even if I shift-click refresh, it doesn't refresh my code. I had to exit the browser and open it again for it to refresh. Perhaps thats a setting. Thank you guys! That explains why it was so weird that it wasn't working!